# Upserting Data using Data Loader with External ID

Tags: data-loader, upsert, externalid, dataloader-batch

I'm using Data Loader in order to Upsert some data within my Org.

I know, that if I will Upsert a record within my CSV that has duplicate External Id value with another record in the file, It will throw me a duplicate error and the record will not be upload.

But i'm not sure - Dose Data loader will not upload the duplicated records at all?

Or it will upload the first record seeing on the CSV file, and then when he hits the other one it will throw a duplicate exception?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will put 2 scenarios over here. I have created following csv file to upload data into my org, where

> `External Site Id` is `External Id` (unique is not selected)
>
> `External Site key` is `External Id` and also `unique`

[image: Dataload_ExternalId]

**Scenario 1:**

> By default, Batch size of dataloader is **"200"**

So, if we perform upsert based on `External Site Id` or `External Site Key`, then in both the cases, Salesforce will try to process both the records in single batch and it will throw the error **"Duplicate External Ids"**

**Scenario 2:**

> Change batch size to **"1"**

Perform upsert based on `External Site Id` or `External Site Key`, then in both the cases, Salesforce will try to process both the records in two different batches and successfully uploads the data.

2 things to be noted here:

1. You will **NOT** receive any errors during upload. both of the records will be processed.
2. **Most importantly**, Salesforce will update data with latest record that has been updated. So, in SFDC we will find **single** record (here the last record) with `External Site Id`

Comment: Hi Santanu Boral, Thank you for the respond! Jso to make sure, I need to use a 1 batch size to avoid this?

Comment: Actually if you make batch size to 1 then it will take longer time if you try to process large volume of data. But at-least you will not receive duplicate error

Comment: or otherwise, when you are preparing the csv you can eliminate duplicate there and then upload the data in SFDC

Comment: So in conclusion, to create a 1 batch size it isnt a solution (I have 160,000 records file). I MUST have a unique records in order to use upsert and avoid duplicates. Thanks again

Comment: please close this ques